# How to check for NULL or empty value in fql (fast search)?

Tags: search, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

I want to check for null or empty field in fql query , I want to add condition to retrieve result when is column not equal empty or null,  I've tried these ways :

```
     <Context>
     <QueryText language='en-US' type='FQL'>and(string("Text"),not(Column_Name:equals(" ")))
     </QueryText>
  </Context>


     <Context>
     <QueryText language='en-US' type='FQL'>and(string("Text"),filter(Column_Name:not(" ")))
     </QueryText>
  </Context>
```

I also tried "^$" regular expression instead of empty string , but doesn't work .

any ideas ??